# MVC - sharing root views with areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-views

So I have some simple views (Lists, Create/Edit) in my project 'root' and I want to use most of the same view in an admin area(real MVC area). The admin view will only have a few differences. So my two main thoughts are:

- Create a partial for all the shared elements, and both views will use that where needed.
- Add like an `IsAdmin` property to my view model and just use that to conditionally add/change elements as needed, so there will only be one view.

Any thoughts, or other ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the views full relative path? return View("~/Views/AdminEdit.cshtml");

Comment: @heymega - Well yeah, that is what I'll do if I go with option 2 and just use one view file. I'm not sure what you meant by that.